# How to select aria-autocomplete input field in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I run into this **autocomplete input text** field. HTML is:

```html
<div id="customfield_11930-single-select" class="aui-ss ajax-ss long-field" data-query="35mm Capture - 2.7.1">
    <input id="customfield_11930-field" class="text aui-ss-field ajs-dirty-warning-exempt" type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-busy="false">
    <div class="ajs-layer-placeholder">
    <span class="icon aui-ss-icon drop-menu noloading">
        <span>More</span>
    </span>
</div>
<select id="customfield_11930" class="single-select long-field hidden js-sprint-picker aui-ss-select" data-saved-state="" data-saved-id="" data-container-class="long-field" name="customfield_11930" style="display: none;" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="" selected="selected"> </option>
</select>
```

What i understand about this HTML is:

`input(customfield_11930-field)` is text field that user input in

`div(ajs-layer-placeholder)` store all the autocomplete/suggestion

`span()` is the place where user's click will pop out autocomplete/suggestion list

`select(customfield_11930)` is where autocomplete/suggestion is shown

So if I use code:

```
myDriver.findElement(By.id("customfield_11930-field")).sendKeys("35mm Capture - 2.7.1");
```

Below screenshot will show:

[image]

**Now how do i select the 1st item in the autocomplete/suggestion list?**

**Is the 'Select' element now populated with all the suggestion list items?**

I do something like:

```
new Select(myDriver.findElement(By.id("customfield_11930"))).selectByVisibleText("35mm Capture - 2.7.1");
```

but it does not work.

Actually i am quite confused at how this type of autocomplete selection menu works, it seems a lot more complicated than a normal dropdown list.

Any explanation from any one? Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After text entry there is a new dynamic field with id `suggestions` you can click the first suggestion by css selector as `#suggestions > li:nth-child(1)`. You can see code below:

Python:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#customfield_11930-field").clear()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#customfield_11930-field").send_keys("35mm Capture - 2.7.1")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#suggestions > li:nth-child(1)").click()
```

Java:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#customfield_11930-field")).clear();
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#customfield_11930-field")).sendKeys("35mm Capture - 2.7.1");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#suggestions > li:nth-child(1)")).click();
```

Comment: @ Mesut Güneş I accepted the answer. Just now click 'is useful'.